# Extracting text from Xpath using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Looking for a way to extract the text from an Xpath using javascript.

Example:
`Xpath: <span>Sometext<span>`

Want to return the value: `Sometext`.

Tried something like this with no luck.

```
 var x_path = 'my_xpath';
 var result = document.evaluate(x_path,document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
 console.log(result);
```

Output is just `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get text/value using this:

var my_xpath = 'some_xpath'
var value1 = document.evaluate(my_xpath ,document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
var x = value1.stringValue;
console.log(x);